# Playing audio on Smartface IO

Tags: smartface.io, playsound

I have been trying to play a sound on a click of a button and ive read everywhere and none of the solutions posted solved the problem.

I use the method stated on the docs website my file is an mp3 and its located in my resources/Sounds folder.

I have also read that there is a known issue in SMF. The only part that gets called in my playSound method below is the finished part

SMF.Multimedia.playSound("woop.wav",
        true, true,
        function() {
            alert("started to play...");
        },
        function() {alert("finished")});

I have the audio file located in resources/sounds folder I have also tried moving it around and I have tried different file formats but without any luck.

Does anyone know a working method to play audio or any concrete info regarding this bug in SMF

Answer (score 1):

Upload "woop.wav" into **assets** folder.Then use this code to play it.

```
SMF.Multimedia.playSound("woop.wav",true, false);
```

I tried both .mp3 and .wav files on Android,it works.[Here](https://smartface.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GUIDE/Audio+and+Video) is the official gudie for `Multimedia`.

Comment: What is .mdi? I know .mid which is a MIDI file (tried that as well and it didnt work)  but I have never heard or found any sound file format that has the extension .mdi. Did that example above work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried that sveral times but still doesn't work. Which smartface app studio are you usng? i have tried to play the sound on a button click and just when my app starts and i have moved the sound file between assets and the resources/sounds folders and nothing. i have tried wav, mp3 and nothing.I am using my Samsung s6 im not sure that this makes any difference. I can get it to vibrate and increase the sound level but not play the file

Comment: I'm currently using Smartface Cloud IDE. It works very well.There is no folder like resources/sounds in Cloud IDE. I think you are using the App Studio.

Comment: yes I am using app studio 4.5.1.5 and im not getting any luck. I will give the cloud IDE a shot and see how i get on. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I have requested an invitation to smartface cloud ide but no reply ... I think smartface has the worst support or they are in over their heads trying to enhance their product but so far they have advertised something tbat doesnt really do the job